# How make rest service to use only TLS V1.2 using java or spring libraries?

Tags: java, spring, tls1.2, using

The service provider who is hosting a rest service is asking to communicate using TLS version 1.2 only.
So now I need to make my application to communicate with that service using TLS v 1.2.

I know, in java8 we have an option of disabling the legacy version of TLS and SSL using the property jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4 in java.security file.

But in a server there will be other process using the same java settings, so I'm worried like if I change for that property in java.security file, then it will be applicable to other services which are using the same settings.

**Question:**
I would like to know if there is any other way to make my rest calls use only particular TLS version, through application code using java/spring libraries ?

Comment: Firstly, it would help if you showed your REST client code since it would help find a solution that works for you. Secondly, if the service provider wants to support TLSv1.2 only, they can configure this on the server side. Then as long as the client supports it, all connections will use TLSv1.2. My opinion is that they should enforce this rather than the client.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `SSLContext` to use the required protocol:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
```

If the client code or library uses HttpsURLConnection then you can set the default `SSLSocketFactory` for all the HTTS Connections:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Or at a per connection level:

```
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = ....;
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
urlConnection.connect();
```

Different libraries may have different systems to provide the `SSLSocketFactory` or `SSLContext`.
For example, if you are using JAX-RS, you can create a REST client that uses the `SSLContext` with:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build();
```